Excel vba lock cell position(address) under resizable table
Issue:
I have an excel sheet where table "table_data" is being resized often. There are few bits of information scattered under the table from column A to column D, therefore when table is resized the information is moving with it. The problem is, that cells below the table pull data from another sheet and have these options attached to them:
.WrapText = True
.EntireRow.AutoFit

So when those cell move up, they resize whole line, therefore information to the right of the table looks disastrous. Below is the example of the "table_data"
Question:
Is there a way to lock the information under the table in place? For e.g. if cells which I need to stay in place are starting from A29 to D32, when table mentioned above resized. I want them to stay the same place, instead they go up by the amount of lines removed in the table. Please note table max lines is 22 as shown above. It can only have less lines. Therefore, table will not overlap with locked cells

This button automatically modifies number of rows in the table, below the code for Modify table button

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim currentRowCount As Long
Dim desiredRowCount As Long
Dim i As Long
protect_quote (0)
' Set the table object
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").ListObjects("table_data")

' Get the current number of rows in the table
currentRowCount = tbl.ListRows.count

' Get the desired number of rows from cell M8
desiredRowCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Range("Set_number_of_lines").Value

' Add or delete rows as needed
If desiredRowCount > currentRowCount Then
    ' Add rows
    For i = currentRowCount + 1 To desiredRowCount
        tbl.ListRows.add
    Next i
ElseIf desiredRowCount < currentRowCount Then
    ' Delete rows
    For i = currentRowCount To desiredRowCount + 1 Step -1
        tbl.ListRows(i).Delete
    Next i
End If
protect_quote (1)

protect_quote is function, which protects and unprotects the sheet
Solution:
My current idea is to create 2d array data_style(), store data and style information in the array, clear moved cells and then restore data and style to original cell locations. I haven't wrote the code yet as it seems inefficient and bulky. I'm hoping there's a better solution before I resort to that. I've started learning VBA about a month ago, that's why I don't know if there's any simpler way to do it
Solution 2:
Very crude, but relatively simple and 100% functional solution is to add line or remove line before line 29:
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim currentRowCount, desiredRowCount, ack_line As Long
Dim i As Long
protect_quote (0)
' Set the table object
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").ListObjects("table_data")
' Get the current number of rows in the table
currentRowCount = tbl.ListRows.count

' Get the desired number of rows from cell M8
desiredRowCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Range("Set_number_of_lines").Value
' Add or delete rows as needed
If desiredRowCount > currentRowCount Then
    ' Add rows
    For i = currentRowCount + 1 To desiredRowCount
        tbl.ListRows.add
        ack_line = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Range("ack_email").Row
        If desiredRowCount <= 22 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").rows(ack_line - 1).Delete
        Else
            If tbl.ListRows.count <= 22 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").rows(ack_line - 1).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
ElseIf desiredRowCount < currentRowCount Then
    ' Delete rows
    For i = currentRowCount To desiredRowCount + 1 Step -1
        ack_line = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Range("ack_email").Row
        If desiredRowCount < 22 Then
            If tbl.ListRows.count <= 22 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").rows(ack_line).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        End If
        tbl.ListRows(i).Delete
    Next i
End If
protect_quote (1)

P.S. all cells which need to be locked in same location belong to range "A29:D32" and the selection is named "email_ship"

It seems to me that you should not be deleting and inserting rows. Instead, just update the table using the table.resize() function to change the whole range over which the table is defined. Then it will not move your other data

Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately when using resize it doesn't remove lines properly, because total line is not part of the table name - it leaves white cells with "#REF" in them between total and the resized table, also resize doesn't work with custom function which is involved in the table and fails to add it to new line

I still think adding and deleting rows of the table in your code is not the right approach, using resize is better.  I suggest you move the total line to the max position before resizing then back to the right row after resizing. You can clear rows if the table reduces in size.  If you have formulas and/or styling within the table then add those in to the table after it has resized if you need to. You can presumably work out what parameters you need in your function calls.

Since I have such a specific problem and problem should've been solved via Resize, but unfortunately due to the way I've built the sheet and VBA script, I cannot use the resize function. Therefore, very crude and inefficient solution I found in my situation is to add or remove a line before the information which needs to stay in same place, depending on the size of the table before it. Here's an example if anyone needs:
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim currentRowCount, desiredRowCount, ack_line As Long
Dim i As Long
protect_quote (0)
' Set the table object
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").ListObjects("table_data")
' Get the current number of rows in the table
currentRowCount = tbl.ListRows.count

' Get the desired number of rows from cell where used inputs amount of lines
desiredRowCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Range("Set_number_of_lines").Value
' Add or delete rows as needed from the table, but also number of lines changed between them depending on table size. If table has more lines than 22, then lock is lifted and info is moving together with table size, so that it wouldn't overlap
If desiredRowCount > currentRowCount Then
    ' Add rows
    For i = currentRowCount + 1 To desiredRowCount
        tbl.ListRows.add
        ack_line = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Range("ack_email").Row
        If desiredRowCount <= 22 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").rows(ack_line - 1).Delete
        Else
            If tbl.ListRows.count <= 22 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").rows(ack_line - 1).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
ElseIf desiredRowCount < currentRowCount Then
    ' Delete rows
    For i = currentRowCount To desiredRowCount + 1 Step -1
        ack_line = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Range("ack_email").Row
        If desiredRowCount < 22 Then
            If tbl.ListRows.count <= 22 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").rows(ack_line).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        End If
        tbl.ListRows(i).Delete
    Next i
End If
protect_quote (1)

